# VSTO - Activate "Track Changes" in an excel workbook with c#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, review

In Excel 2007 you have the button "Track Changes" in the "Review" Ribbon.
How can I perform this action through c#?

Comment: Can't you translate [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721160/excel-vba-macro-to-track-changes-in-separate-sheet)?

Comment: No it leads to the same exception.

Comment: Are you sure your workbook is **shared**? Please read the accepted answer carefully, especially the last paragraph.

Comment: Are there any kind of prerequisites which if have to set in order to successfully set the excel document to "shared"? Because when I use `XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange` as Access Mode instead of `XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared` the file is saved. Otherwise I get an exception.

Comment: Don't you have the same behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line of code should do

*Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.HighlightChangesOnScreen = true;*

make sure the document has been saved.

Comment: I run it from an addin as `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ThisWorkbook.HighlightChangesOnScreen = true;` and get the Exception `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

Comment: The same with `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ThisWorkbook.HighlightChangesOptions(XlHighlightChangesTime.xlAllChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);`

Comment: Did you shared your Workbook?

Comment: This worked for me ' workSheet.SaveAs(Filename:"Book1.xlsx", AccessMode: Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared);
            workSheet.HighlightChangesOptions(When: Excel.XlHighlightChangesTime.xlAllChanges);
            workSheet.HighlightChangesOnScreen = true;'

Comment: I'm trying to save it, but it ends always in an an exception wenn I call `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ThisWorkbook.SaveAs("test.xslx", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);`

Comment: See in the comments mentioned above.

Comment: Are you able to share your workbook manually. If you cant share check this http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=87152

Comment: I can click on the "Review => Share workbook" button and everthing works fine. Excel just want to save the document.