Macro to turn on track changes in Excel files
I am trying to implement track changes in exported Excel files. I have a master file that uses Power Query to create data tables from a master source. The data tables need to be distributed so that users can edit the content locally, not in the data source. The data export to separate files (one table to one workbook) works fine, but I get a run-time error 1004 for HighlightChangesOptions when the macro tries to turn on track changes.
Update: Track changes activated by adding AccessMode:=xlShared to SaveAs
    Sub CopyTablesToNewFiles_DeleteConnections_TrackChanges()
    Dim wbSource, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim savePath,  currentDate, wsName, Filename As String

    currentDate = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")

    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In wbSource.Worksheets
        ws.Copy
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        
            'Remove connections to original query
            Do While wbNew.Connections.Count > 0
            wbNew.Connections.Item(ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count).Delete
            Loop
            
            'Convert table to range to support track changes (only 1 table in sheet)
            Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
            For Each objList In wsNew.ListObjects
                objList.Unlist
            Next objList
            
        savePath = "C:\Path\Test\"

    With wbNew
        '.ExclusiveAccess '- gives run-time error 1004
        'can activate Track Changes by adding xlShared to the SaveAs
        .SaveAs Filename:=savePath & currentDate & "_" & ws.Name & ".xlsx", AccessMode:=xlShared
        .HighlightChangesOptions When:=xlAllChanges
        .ListChangesOnNewSheet = False
        .HighlightChangesOnScreen = True
    End With
    
    wbNew.Save
        wbNew.Close
    Next ws

    'wbSource.Close
End Sub


Please have look onto https://stackoverflow.com/a/721673. Maybe that's the same problem.

Please don't post code in the comments. Edit your question instead. In according the documentation of ExclusiveAccess:  If the specified workbook isn't open as a shared list, this method fails.

try using ExclusiveAccess after you have saved the workbook

Still gives Run-time error 1004

I have chosen a different route - adding a Worksheet_Change for the sheet and exporting the file as macro-enabled:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 27 End Sub
